# check if any other copy is in process before my xcopy command

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have xcopy batch utility which copies files to network drive.

Is there any way to find if any other user is copying files to the same above location before i start??

The whole idea is to prevent overwriting the files when other users are running the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's a good question indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not absolutely sure but you can use `TASKLIST` dos command like below; which will get you the information whether an `XCOPY` exe is running already.

```
TASKLIST /FO TABLE /NH /FI "USERNAME ne NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /FI "STATUS eq running" /FI "IMAGENAME eq XCOPY.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

```dos
9>"w:\target\file.lock" (
    xcopy "r:\source\*" "w:\target"
) && ( del "w:\target\file.lock" )
```

Use a lock file in your target folder.

What it does is redirect to a file (and lock it) inside the target folder the data sent to the stream 9 (there are 10 streams, `0=stdin`, `1=stdout`, `2=stderr`, `3-9` user defined). Nothing will be written to the stream but the output file will be locked.

As the redirection is wrapping the `xcopy` command, the lock on the file is maintained until the command ends.

Comment: That's a nice thing to know; can you explain little more on `lock` part a bit. Curious to know. +1 for the new thing.

Comment: That's a real nice thing to know. Does the `file.lock` needs to be exist physically (or) it's just a placeholder lock (kind a semaphore)?

Comment: @Rahul, standard `>` redirect behaviour. If the file exists it is overwritten. If the file does not exist it is created. In both cases, a write lock is held while redirection is active. If the file is locked, it is not possible to write to it so the full command fails as the redirections are handled before starting to execute the involved commands.